# In bash, can I set an environment variable that executes a command only the first time it's accessed?

Tags: bash, terminal

Basically I would like to do something like

```
export PWD=$(run pwd the first time this environment variable is accessed, 
store the value, 
reuse that value for each subsequent access)
```

Comment: You can't defer the execution of the command substitution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take you to be asking for a variable whose value is determined by executing a command the first time it is *read*, which value is then cached for subsequent reads.

**No, you cannot do that**.  A variable's value is established only when it is assigned, not when it is read.  You could do something similar with a shell function (and a supporting variable), however:

```
my_pwd() {
  if [[ -z "$_saved_pwd" ]]; then
    export _saved_pwd=$(pwd)
  fi
  echo "${_saved_pwd}"
}
export -f my_pwd
```

With that in place, the `my_pwd` command will execute `pwd` and store the result the first time it runs.  Every time it runs, it will output the result of that first `pwd` command.  That may serve your purposes directly, or you can also capture the result for other uses via `$(my_pwd)`.

Comment: There's a serious problem (or at least limitation) with this, though: if you run it with `$(my_pwd)`, it runs in a subshell, so any value it sets for `_saved_pwd` will be lost when the subshell exits.

Comment: That is a valid criticism, @GordonDavisson.  One can, of course, overcome that by running `my_pwd` directly once.  In any event, it is secondary to and even supportive of the main answer (bolded), which is that what the OP seems to be asking for is not possible as such.

Answer (score 0):

If it's shell-specific, try to put it in `.bashrc;` if it's not, put it in `.profile`. Also make sure to put `[[ $- != *i* ]] && return` on the top of `.bashrc`. It would be more clear if you can tell how you want to use it.